# How to get all the tags on a specific branch with GitLabAPI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm new to Gitlab API, I know how to create a tag on a specific branch, let's say I have several branches on my repository, and I created several tags on each branch. Now I want get all the tags on a specific branch with GitLabAPI. I've read the [Branchs API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html) and [Tags API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/tags.html) docs carefully, however was unable to find an answer to my question. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure what you're trying to accomplish as you literally described your problem with one short sentence, so it will be more of a guess.

If what you want to do is to create GitLab tag for a specific commit for a specific branch, you simply do that as you can define branch when creating it. Will not post description of how it should be done as there is documentation.

With GitLabAPI(as you wanted based on you problem description) follow this link:

[How to with GitLabAPI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/releases.html)

And instead of Release tag just make same steps for any other tag. For tagging from console you should follow this one:

[How to with git](https://pl.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/inspecting-a-repository/git-tag)

If you're looking for a way to find specific tag with GitLabAPI just go that way:

> Repository->Tags->Filter by tag name

Tags are unique across the whole repository.

For doing checkout from console:

`git checkout <tag>`

Your consternation, I believe, comes from misunderstanding the idea of tags. It's kind of a snapshot of repository at specific point, might be for release, may be for backup purposes, does not matter, it's up to you. Important part is that no matter where you will place it, it has to be unique in scope of a whole repository not just a branch you place it. There is no way to create two same tags on two different branches, git won't let you. Read info from links and everything should be clear.

If my answer is not what you were looking for, expand your question to get more proper and accurate one.